# Remove Logs Using proguard android studio

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Hi I have try different ways for removing the logs in release apk, but nothing works. I'm using android studio 1.5.1 and android api 22 here is my configuration

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles '/Users/cesar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

in the proguard-rules.pro I add this

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int e(...);
}
```

I'm creating signed apk for release but I still see the logs in the console, I know that I have to use optimize file after doing some research but I still see the logs in the console.

Comment: what is I don't want to minify?

Comment: Please post error log if minifyEnabled true

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

with your proguard rules.

Comment: what if I don't want to minfy?

Comment: If I add minify true I get error Warning: there were 54 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.

Comment: minify will run proguard